# MorphMany relationship returning empty array in laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel, polymorphism

I'm trying to return the product data with image with Morph relationship

I can save the data, however when I'm retrieving it, the images field has empty value.

**Product Model:**

```
protected $fillable=['name', 'description'];

public function images(){
  $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Image Model:**

```
protected $fillable=['imagable_id', 'imagable_type', 'file_name'];

public function imagable(){
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Product Controller:** So this where I want to retrieve the product with image on it.

```
public function index(){
  return Product::with('images')->get();
}
```

This controller return only the product data, but it has empty images array field.

Answer (score 0):

Your product model definition for `images()` is pointing at the `Category` model and is a `belongsToMany()` vs. a `morphMany()`. You should also adjust the spelling of `imageable` to be correct.

Try adjusting your relationships like this

Product Model:

```php
public function images(){
  $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

Image Model:

```php
public function imageable(){
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```